# Radiator Hose was unattached!

Tags: engine, coolant, radiator, infiniti, hose

so I have a 2015 Infiniti QX70 that I took in for its routine oil change (Infiniti dealership). Before they completed the job, they recommended I replace the top radiator hose, bottom hose, and some type of belt. I agreed to fix all recommendations and picked up my car the next morning. 
I drove my car 20 miles home that day, woke up the next and drove another 20 miles to work. I left work and drove about 15 miles home (rain) when all of a sudden my car  begins to stall, smoke, shake, and came to a complete stop (in the fast lane to the freeway)

Roadside assistance came and guided me to safety. He did a check and saw that my temp
Was all the way on the H. 
He asked me to lift my hood, and within 5 mins asked me if I had just gotten my car fixed. Of course I said yes and his reply was “there is coolant all over and your radiator hose isn’t attached”
He told me to call Infiniti right away but he would try to put it on for me. After securing the hose he tells me the safety component for the clamp was still intact and that may have been the reason. Either way he added water and had me on my way.

What kind of damage likely happened as a result of this hose, based on the distance I drove and the “symptoms” my car experienced??

Comment: Sounds like your engine seized due to getting too hot.  It could have caused some serious damage to the cylinders.

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand correctly, one of your radiator hoses (I'm assuming the UPPER one here since if it was the lower one, they never would have been able to fill it with coolant to begin with) was disconnected or (more likely) became disconnected at some point while you were driving.

If that's the case and your engine overheated to the point of stopping, as it sounds happened, then your engine is almost certainly damaged and the shop who did the work is responsible.

First of all DOCUMENT everything now while it's fresh in your mind in case they are reluctant to accept the responsibility.  Contact the service manager and let him know what's happened.  State only facts that you know, don't provide any opinion of your own.

Hopefully this is a professional operation and they will admit their fault and make it right, which in the case means a replacement engine.

Good luck and hopefully you can resolve this without a lawyer but a 2015 QX70 is still a valuable vehicle and you likely could have continued to drive it for years to come.

Comment: Thank you. The work was done by Infiniti. Hopefully they do the right thing. The next morning the car was towed to them. 

I really do need to start documenting everything because of the severity. 

Roadside assistance has already sent me a letter in the mail detailing what he saw. 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If I was to throw an opinion out here, I'd suggest the radiator hose was not fitted correctly, where it sealed at first, but then through pressure become disconnected, blowing go-go juice everywhere. This means it could have easily been upper or lower. Also, while I agree this could have caused damage, it doesn't mean it *has caused damage*. I'd still document it. I do completely agree the shop is at fault here.